# Direct2D to XPS file without print queue

Tags: winapi, direct2d, xps

Direct2D allows printing via `ID2D1Device::CreatePrintControl`, which presumably renders an XPS as an intermediate representation.  With an XPS Document Writer or other printer, I can create an xps file via redirection from Direct2D.  Can I create an `ID2D1PrintControl` or `ID2D1DeviceContext` against an XPS document without a print queue?

Is there some `ID2D1DeviceMagic::CreatePrintControlOnStream(IStream* ...)` or `IPrintDocumentPackageTargetFactoryMagic::CreateOnXpsOM(IXpsOMPage* pPage, ...)` I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked Simon Mourier's answer? Is that worked?

Comment: I haven't.  It makes sense (hence the upvote), but I've not gotten to verify.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT, worked perfectly. [C++ sample](https://github.com/mgaffigan/D2DPdfPrintSample/blob/master/PdfToXps/PdfToXps.cpp) and [C# Nuget library](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.PdfPrinting#readme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not magic, but almost. You can implement [IPrintDocumentPackageTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/documenttarget/nn-documenttarget-iprintdocumentpackagetarget) COM interface yourself and use it when calling the [ID2D1Device::CreatePrintControl method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1device-createprintcontrol(iwicimagingfactory_iprintdocumentpackagetarget_constd2d1_print_control_properties__id2d1printcontrol)).

In your implementation you can delegate the work to the [IXpsOMObjectFactory::CreatePackageWriterOnStream method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dd372554(v=vs.85)), so, it can be something like this:

```
CTarget *target = new CTarget();

auto hr = d2dDevice->CreatePrintControl(
    wicFactory,
    target, // use my own target
    nullptr,
    &printControl
);

delete target;
```

This is the `CTarget` sample class that implements `IPrintDocumentPackageTarget`, and `IXpsDocumentPackageTarget`:

```
// needs <initguid.h>, <shlwapi.h> and shlwapi.lib
class CTarget : public IPrintDocumentPackageTarget, IXpsDocumentPackageTarget
{
    // make sure this get release *before* CoUninitialize call
    CComPtr<IXpsOMObjectFactory> _factory; // uses ATL needs <atlbase.h>

public:
    CTarget() {}

    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        static QITAB rgqit[] =
        {
            QITABENT(CTarget, IPrintDocumentPackageTarget),
            QITABENT(CTarget, IXpsDocumentPackageTarget),
            { 0},
        };

        return QISearch(this, rgqit, riid, ppv);
    }

    // for testing we just send something static
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef() { return 1; }; STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release() { return 1; };

    // IPrintDocumentPackageTarget
    STDMETHODIMP GetPackageTargetTypes(UINT32* targetCount, GUID** targetTypes)
    {
        if (!targetCount || !targetTypes) return E_INVALIDARG;
        *targetTypes = (GUID*)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(GUID));
        if (!*targetTypes)
        {
            *targetCount = 0;
            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }

        *targetCount = 1;
        **targetTypes = ID_DOCUMENTPACKAGETARGET_MSXPS;
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetPackageTarget(REFGUID guidTargetType, REFIID riid, void** ppvTarget)
    {
        if (guidTargetType == ID_DOCUMENTPACKAGETARGET_MSXPS)
            return QueryInterface(riid, ppvTarget);

        return E_FAIL;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Cancel()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    // IXpsDocumentPackageTarget
    STDMETHODIMP GetXpsOMPackageWriter(IOpcPartUri* documentSequencePartName, IOpcPartUri* discardControlPartName, IXpsOMPackageWriter** packageWriter)
    {
        // here you can create your own stream, file, memory, etc.
        CComPtr<IStream> stream;
        SHCreateStreamOnFile(L"c:\\temp\\d2d1.xps", STGM_CREATE | STGM_WRITE, &stream);

        // ... and delegate to factory w/o more effort
        // you can also configure custom properties, etc.
        return _factory->CreatePackageWriterOnStream(stream, FALSE, XPS_INTERLEAVING_OFF, documentSequencePartName, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, discardControlPartName, packageWriter);
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetXpsOMFactory(IXpsOMObjectFactory** xpsFactory)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        if (!_factory)
        {
            if (FAILED(hr = _factory.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XpsOMObjectFactory)))
                return hr;
        }

        return _factory.QueryInterface(xpsFactory);
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetXpsType(XPS_DOCUMENT_TYPE* documentType)
    {
        if (!documentType) return E_INVALIDARG;
        *documentType = XPS_DOCUMENT_TYPE_XPS;
        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's pretty magic, @simon-mourier.  Thanks for the continued help.  [C++ sample](https://github.com/mgaffigan/D2DPdfPrintSample/blob/master/PdfToXps/PdfToXps.cpp) and [C#/Nuget library](https://github.com/mgaffigan/Rmg.PdfPrinting#readme)